# Modify a date given in string format

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am given a date "12-31-2020" in string format, and I need to subtract 3 days, but I need the output "12-28-2020" in string format as well . I think I need to convert it to date format first in order to do subtraction. Can you help me what function I should use. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it using only the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module included the standard-library. The code first converts the string into a `datetime.datetime` object, subtracts a 3 day `timedelta` from it, and lastly prints out the result in the same format.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_string = '31-12-2020'
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d-%m-%Y') - timedelta(days=3)
print(date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))  # -> 28-12-2020
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: they are both good answers. can i accept both?

Comment: No unfortunately. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

use a very powerful `dateutil` lib from python. You can do almost any kind of fun with it.

```
from dateutil import parser, relativedelta

date_string = '31-12-2020'
print((parser.parse(date_string) - relativedelta.relativedelta(days=3)).strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
```